# Typescript correct function typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm new to typescript and I'm not quite sure how to properly describe the return value type of a function.
I have some abstract class and method

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export interface RequestMiddleware {
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void
}

export abstract class ValidateRequest {
    abstract checkData(params?: any[]): RequestMiddleware
}
```

And the class that inherits this abstract and implements the method

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { ValidateRequest, RequestMiddleware } from './contract/ValidateRequest';


class AuthSignUp extends ValidateRequest {
    checkData(params?: any[]): RequestMiddleware {
        return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

        }
    }
}

export default new AuthSignUp();
```

But I noticed that I can remove the arguments (or change the number of arguments) and typescript will not give errors

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { ValidateRequest, RequestMiddleware } from './contract/ValidateRequest';


class AuthSignUp extends ValidateRequest {
    checkData(params?: any[]): RequestMiddleware {
        return () => {}
    }
}

export default new AuthSignUp();
```

How to do the correct typing, i.e., that the arguments of the return function checkData correspond to the described interface RequestMiddleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript allows for function implementations with lower [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) by design. For example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAKgdwPZQLxQBQEMBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0UFhplNAlJgHzHlXUDcAKAEBjVEQDOwKADMAltUmF4SNJhy56Fdhi64oAagZ8oAehNRUAaxFjJUcRFFE4ShCnRY823cbMXrTnbAABbyLrBuqp7eUAAMvuZWAkA)

```ts
type AddTwo = (a: number, b: number) => number;

const first: AddTwo = (a, b) => a + b; // ok
const second: AddTwo = (a) => a; // ok
const third: AddTwo = () => 0; // ok
```

This is described in the [Overloads and Callbacks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#overloads-and-callbacks) section of the handbook:

> ### Overloads and Callbacks
>
> ❌ **Don't** write separate overloads that differ only on callback arity:
>
> ```ts
> /* WRONG */
> declare function beforeAll(action: () => void, timeout?: number): void;
> declare function beforeAll(
>   action: (done: DoneFn) => void,
>   timeout?: number
> ): void;
> ```
>
> ✅ **Do** write a single overload using the maximum arity:
>
> ```ts
> /* OK */
> declare function beforeAll(
>   action: (done: DoneFn) => void,
>   timeout?: number
> ): void;
> ```
>
> ❔ **Why:** It's always legal for a callback to disregard a parameter, so there's no need for the shorter overload.
> Providing a shorter callback first allows incorrectly-typed functions to be passed in because they match the first overload.